# IDE for Python ( like Visual Studio with visual assist X )?

Tags: python, ide, visual-assist

I use for C/C++ Visual studio 2012 with Visual Assist X plugin. 
Now I'm going to learn Python. I need good IDE for Python and my main requirement
-very good intelli/autocomplete feature in IDE ( I don't like notepad or Python shell )
Can you recommended IDE for my requirement?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81584/what-ide-to-use-for-python

Comment: try pydev too, has lots of the toys you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

I struggled a lot before finding a good IDE for Python. At the moment I'm using [PyCharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) which has a lot of features I got used to with other languages and IDEs, such as very good syntax highlighting, code completion, structure navigation, documentation linking, VCS integration (with live diff tool) and so on.

Note: it's not free though, but you can do a free and full-features 30-days trial.

Answer (score 3):

> very good intelli/autocomplete feature in IDE

*It will be very difficult to find a good IDE for python.* The main reason is that **your requirement is very *very* difficult to be achieved**, if not downright impossible, due to the fact that python is **dynamically** bound, *so utilities can not be certain about what goes where* (as they do in a statically bound languages, such as `java` or `c#`) so as to create a reliable autocomplete feature in an IDE.

That said, in my opinion you might be better served using a plain text editor (`vim` quickly comes to mind, if you are on windows something along the lines of [notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) will do) and then use the python vm of your choice to run and/or debug your code.

If you are so inclined to use an IDE nonetheless, [Aptana studio](http://www.aptana.com/) (or just [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) with [pydev](http://pydev.org/)) might prove adequate. Visual Studio is also a choice if you choose to pair it with [Python tools for Visual studio](http://pytools.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You may use APTANA, Geany or ipython for your practice! I would prefer APTANA or GEANY
Eclipse is also a good IDE for python too!

Comment: I personally don't like pyDev for Eclipse, even though it is better than the average IDEs for Python. Slow, many imperfections and not at the same level as for Java.

Comment: Then Try Aptana ;) btw APTANA gives a facility of debugging python code.

Answer (score 0):

WingIDE is my preferred ide. It has pretty good intelligent fill.

Answer (score 0):

These days I go with Sublime Text for editing everything (http://www.sublimetext.com) and bpython (http://bpython-interpreter.org) as my Python shell.

Perhaps these other threads on Stack Overflow may be of additional help:

[What IDE to use for Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81584/what-ide-to-use-for-python)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126753/is-there-a-good-free-python-ide-for-windows

[Which is the best IDE for Python For Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899732/which-is-the-best-ide-for-python-for-windows)

Answer (score 0):

I also relatively new to python (1 month..) after struggling with idlex for a few weeks ,i found  [pyscripter](https://code.google.com/p/pyscripter/) and im very happy with it ,has almost perfect auto-complete for python! As big plus .. it made me stop wishing there where a version of netbeans for python !